# Ubuntu 18.04 is in login loop after python 3.7.2 install

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I upgraded my Dell PC from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 successfully. Since 18.04 is preloaded with python-3.6.5 or .7 and I wanted to use the latest python-3.7. so I downloaded the source release of python-3.7.2 and installed it. It went fine except the up-arrow key for Python shell command recall didn't work. Then when I tried to log out, the mouse and cursor freeze. I've experienced this even before python-3.7.2 install. The real bad thing is that after restarting the PC, it is stuck at console login. Every time I typed in a valid password, the screen would flash and loop back to the login prompt. I have tried python-3.7.1 install and the result is the same.

Below is the install procedure I used according to Python-3.7.2/README.rst

```
~/Downloads$ tar -xf Python-3.7.2.tar.xz 
~/Downloads/Python-3.7.2$ configure
~/Downloads/Python-3.7.2$ make
~/Downloads/Python-3.7.2$ sudo make install
```

zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
Makefile:1130: recipe for target 'install' failed

```
   36  configure --with-zlib=/usr/include
   41  sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
   42  make
   44  sudo make install
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
Makefile:1130: recipe for target 'install' failed

```
   51  sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev 
   66  sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
   65  sudo make install
```

The above procedure also fixed the up-arrow problem. However, I noticed that after the first "sudo make install" python-3.7, the logout and reboot are already stuck in a login loop.

I also went back to Ubuntu 16.04, it didn't seem to have the logout freeze issue, but it did have the login loop problem with the python-3.7 install. BTW, their default python (3.5.2 for Ubuntu 16.04 and 3.6.7 for Ubuntu 18.04) works just fine.

Does anyone have this problem or any fix for it?

Comment: Reinstall. When you overwrite distro-provided binaries, you put your system into an unsupportable state.

Comment: Next time, consider using a package manager such as Nix, which will install its own binaries in a location that's outside the PATH until and unless one explicitly tries to enter an environment where they're present. That way the OS's Python install is unmodified, and only shells or user accounts that *request* an out-of-band install get one.

Comment: ...now, you may be able to recover things by deleting the binaries from `/usr/local/bin` (if there really was no `--path=/usr` on the `./configure`), but that's more a system-administration question than a software-development one -- you'd have the same set of problems with the same set of fixes if you overwrote (or, in the `/usr/local/bin` case, overrode) any other system-critical distro-maintained package, so this isn't Python- or programming-specific.

Comment: For guidance on asking Ubuntu's package manager to validate whether your packages were overwritten, and recover/reinstall if they were, our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) may be more appropriate.

Comment: I strongly recommend pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: @geckos, Nix is pyenv, *but universal*. You can use it to manage Python installs and packages, Ruby installs and packages, Node installs and packages, Golang libraries, random other software, etc; it's complete enough to have a whole standalone distro based on it, yet to also be usable on top of other Linux distros and on MacOS.

Comment: To build your own python without overwriting the system python, use `make altinstall` see the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html#building-python)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I fixed this issue this way:

1 - Ctrl + Alt + F3

2 - type login and password

3 - sudo nano /etc/environment

4 - remove any other reference after PATH is set

From this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
            
PATH=$PATH:/home/carlos/Android/Sdk
            
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

To this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/carlos/Android/Sdk"
    
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Before considering reinstalling completely, press CTRL+ALT+F3 in the login screen to access the command line and try this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064759/purge-and-reinstall-ubuntu-desktop

and this:

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=repair+ubuntu+from+command+line&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Make sure python points to python2.7 and python3 to the default python version. I pointed python to python3.8 . That was a mistake, DON'T do that. If you have done it, have a look at the update-alternatives command to repoint python to python 2.7. Im glad I could repair it. Also reinstall python3-apt and python-apt by running sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-apt and sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt